# Find $x\in[1,49]$ such that $x\equiv49^{49}\bmod50$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find $x\in[1,49]$ such that $x\equiv49^{49}\bmod50$

How do I go about solving this? Can I use Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
49^{49}&\equiv(-1)^{49}\bmod50\\
&\equiv-1\bmod50\\
&\equiv49\bmod50\end{align}$$

Comment: So $x=49$? $49\equiv49^{49}(\bmod50)$?

Comment: @SanderB Yes.${}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$49\equiv -1 \pmod {50}$$

thus

$$x\equiv49^{49}\equiv -1 \pmod {50}\implies x\equiv 49 \pmod {50}$$

NOTE

you can’t use FLT since 50 is not prime